# R matlib plotEqn, how do you plot 4 variable equations?

Tags: r

I get an error message of only handles two-variable equations, is there any function that makes plotEqn available for 4 variables?

```
A <- matrix(c(0, 1, 1, -2, 1, 2, -1, 0, 2, 4, 1, -3, 1, -4, -7, -1),
            nrow = 4,
            ncol = 4,
            byrow = T)
b <- c(-3, 2, -2, -19)

Solve(A, b, fractions = TRUE)
plotEqn(A, b)
```

Comment: How would you expect a `plotEqn` for a 4-variable system of equations to look? Conceptually, this would be a collection of overlapping 3D "slices" of a 4 dimensional space. Even if you _could_ represent this on a 2D computer monitor it would be almost impossible to understand. There is a `plotEqn3D` function that uses openGL to plot intersecting planes in a 3D space. This is hard enough to understand. Or am I misunderstanding what you are trying to do?

Comment: I expect 4 lines in a plot representing the 4 equations I was writing 0 + b + c + -2d= -3, a + 2b - c + 0 = 2, 2a + 4b + 1c - 3d = -2, a - 4b -7c -1d = -19, I just wanted the 4 equations to be graphed using plotEqn(A,b) in 2d I don't expect it to be in 4d. Sorry for the misunderstanding explanation.

Comment: but that's my point - an equation with four variables _can't_ be plotted as a line. If you have an equation with two variables like `y - x = 0` then you can plot that as a line. With three variables like `z - y - x = 0` you can't plot it as a line. It's not the equation for a line - it's the equation for a plane. An equation of 4 variables is a volume, not a line. How would a plot of `2a + 4b + 1c - 3d = -2` look if you tried to draw it on paper? What would the x and y axes be?

Comment: Oh sorry for being a dunderhead thank you for clarifying! Take care<3

Comment: you're hardly a dunderhead. You're programming linear algebra! Thinking in higher dimensional spaces comes naturally to no-one.